# eBPF program fails to attach because of null pointer exception

Tags: c, nullpointerexception, unions, ebpf

I have an eBPF programs that currently fails to attach to trace point `syscalls/sys_exit_mmap`; [`ebpf.NewCollectionWithOptions()`](https://github.com/cilium/ebpf/blob/v0.12.3/collection.go#L366) throws an error: "invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x6ab850]".

Here is the relevant part of my source code. The root cause is apparently in `e->sys_exit_mmap_ret = (__s32)ctx.ret`, for if I assign `0` (i.e. do not use `ctx`) the error goes away. What could be wrong here?

```
struct rb_event {
        __u16 opcode;
        union {
                // ...
                struct {
                        __s32 sys_exit_mmap_ret;
                };
        };
};

// see /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls/sys_exit_mmap/format
struct sys_exit_mmap_ctx {
        __s64 ret;
};

SEC("tracepoint/syscalls/sys_exit_mmap")
int sys_exit_mmap(
        struct sys_exit_mmap_ctx *ctx
) {
        struct rb_event *e;
        e = bpf_ringbuf_reserve(&rb, sizeof(*e), 0);
        if (e == NULL) {
                return 0;
        }

        e->opcode = OPCODE_SYS_EXIT_MMAP;
        e->sys_exit_mmap_ret = (__s32)ctx->ret;

        bpf_ringbuf_submit(e, 0);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a rookie mistake: my `struct rb_event` was missing header fields as e.g. referred to as `struct trace_entry` and `syscall_nr` [here](https://github.com/anakryiko/bpf-ringbuf-examples/blob/main/src/common.h) and [here](https://easychair.org/publications/preprint_open/Tgqk) respectively:

```
struct trace_entry {
    short unsigned int type;
    unsigned char flags;
    unsigned char preempt_count;
    int pid;
};

long syscall_nr;
```

These also show up e.g. also in `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/sched/sched_process_exec/format` (16 bytes of header fields for a trace event in general) and `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls/sys_exit_kill/format` (16 + bytes of header fields for a syscall in particular).